# Adapter not showing data after installing app from playstore

Tags: java, android, kotlin

so i am working on android app programmed in java which shows a list of animals sounds in recycler view. The app works fine when i install it on my device from android studio but when i upload the apk to play console and install from play store the adapter becomes real mess and apps gets crashing untill i clear cache and app data from settings.

Here is what app looks like on first install from play store (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTQkX.jpg)

When i clear cache and app data from settings and relaunch the app it works absolutely fine.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPbgM.jpg)

I have tries all possible solutions which i found online but they could not help. Can anybody explain why this occurs and whats the solution to this?

**Update:** Following @Tenfour4,s comment i switched to production build in android studio but surprisingly app is working fine . The issue only occurs when app is uploaded to play console and installed from there.

Comment: You can switch to a production build instead of debug build in Android Studio and then you’ll be able to easily test and view stack traces. This probably has something to do with reflection and minification.

Comment: are you using firebase

Comment: Yes I am using firebase